# Unwanted space after figure environment

Tags: spacing, floats

When the figure environment directly follows a `\[ ... \]` environment an unwanted space occurs in the output. It obviously seems to be an endlinechar which is changed into a space.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\[ a  = b. \]
\begin{figure}
  figure
\end{figure}
Text\\
Text

\[ a  = b. \]
\begin{figure}
  figure
\end{figure}%
Text\\
Text

\end{document}
```

I know I can get rid of this adding a `%` after `\end{figure}` or generally by adding `\ignorespaces` to the figure environment with [etoolbox](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox)'s `\AfterEndEnvironment`.

My question is: is this a bug or expected behaviour? And if it is a bug who do I send a report?

*EDIT:* It seems my example was not really a minimal one. As it turns out the display environment is not necessary to get the space:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
a%
\begin{figure}
  \caption{A}
\end{figure}
b

and

c\\
d%
\begin{figure}
  \caption{B}
\end{figure}
e

vs.

f%
\begin{figure}
  \caption{C}
\end{figure}%
g

\end{document}
```

In case I didn't make it clear enough: I am not interested in a way to avoid the space -- I know already how to do that. I admit that such information might be useful for other readers, though.

I rather want to know if this behaviour is to be expected of the `figure` environment or a bug?

Comment: In your example both figures are located at the top of the page.

Comment: I know but that seems not to be the point, or am I wrong?

Comment: As I explained, `\begin{figure}` eats a space before it (if there is), but `\end{figure}` doesn't eat a space after it. In cases (ab) and (de) there's a space after `\end{figure}`; in case (fg) there isn't.

Comment: @egreg so you're saying this is expected (and wanted?) benahviour? Is that for a purpose?

Comment: It's expected; you just insert a `figure` environment and don't worry about spaces. Just don't put them after displayed equations and, as I said, it's usually better to put them between paragraphs.

Comment: I too have a same problem. But non of the solutions are working. What is the way out ?

Comment: @Naveen The way out is to stick to good LaTeX practice and only use the `{figure}` environment _between_ paragraphs.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Inserting the `figure` environment there is not the best idea. For example, even if you say `\begin{figure}[htp]` and the `h` option can be honored, the figure will *not* be printed just after the display.

A `figure` environment inserted in the mid of a paragraph cancels the space before it, rather than ignoring spaces after it. But in that case it has nothing to cancel out.

I always put my `figure` and `table` environment *between* paragraphs.

If you want to show a picture representing what's in the displayed formula, it's better to put the figure (not in a figure environment) *inside* the display: the environments available with `amsmath` allow for multiline displays.

Comment: Thanks. I actually asked more out of curiosity. I completely agree that this placement is not the best idea.